# Does the android screen capture file contain any informations about the source device?

Tags: android, device, smartphone, screen-capture

Is we have a screen capture token on android  , what information can we get from that file about the source device ( we can know the screen resolution for exemple , but what else  ? ) .

Comment: Have you tried looking at the metadata? Also, does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: I am asking about the meta data , how to get them

Comment: @HassenDhia Apps exist in the play store, as do image processing libraries that can find the metadata for you. Asking for offsite resources is offtopic though.

Answer (score 0):

as I know, the basic screenshot have the default jpg metadata, which contain just basic date and maybe the android version of the device.
but if you want to look into the metadata of a photo you can try to look for EXIF tool to get it.